# Displaying a Future List Function Firebase GetX

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions, flutter-getx

I'm trying to create a user feed, just like that of twitter using Firebase & GetX.
In the code snippet is my function..

```
List<PostModel> postListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
  return PostModel(
    id: doc.id,
    text: (doc.data() as dynamic)["text"] ?? "",
    creator: (doc.data() as dynamic)["creator"] ?? "",
    timestamp: (doc.data() as dynamic)["timestamp"] ?? 0,
  );
}).toList();
}

Future<List<PostModel>> getFeed() async {
List<String> usersFollowing = await UserService() //['uid1', 'uid2']
    .getUserFollowing(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").where('creator', whereIn: usersFollowing)
.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
.get();

return postListFromSnapshot(querySnapshot);
}
```

What I want to do is to display the Future function getFeed(), I'm using GetX for state management. So, my problem is how can I display the result of this function using a ListView.Builder()

Here's how I used the Future builder

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _.listPost,
  initialData: [PostModel(id: "2", creator: "Fm", text: "Testing", timestamp: Timestamp.now())],
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData == null){
      return Text("Data is available");
    } else{
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.toString().length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          PostModel posts = snapshot.data[index];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(posts.text)
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  },
)
```

And here's the error I got

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](3)
```

It also pointed to an error on the
PostModel post line.. the [index] to be precise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Well, did you try to use a FutureBuilder as described? What happened when you did? Did you get errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your `AsyncSnapshot snapshot` an `AsyncSnapshot<List<PostModel>> snapshot`. That is not your primary problem, but it will make things a lot easier to have proper typing and not have to guess around using `dynamic`.

Your problem is that `hasData` is a `bool`. It is either `true` or `false`, but never `null`. I wonder how you got that line past your compiler. Are you using an outdated version of Flutter? You should check this, your compiler is your friend, if it isn't helping you properly, this will be a hard and rocky road.

Anyway, you should check whether there is data, if there is none, you are still waiting:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _.listPost,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PostModel>> snapshot){
    if(!snapshot.hasData){
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      final postList = snapShot.requireData;

      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: postList .length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          final post = postList[index];
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(post.text)
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  },
)
```